# Symfony update collection form - replace picture doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

(Symfony 5)

I'm trying to update an object which have a collectionform of pictures. Adding and removing pictures works but updating one / replacing it doesn't.
When I try to replace the picture it add a new picture but keep the old one too.
I want to replace the picture, so removing the old one and add the new one.

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/tricks/edit/{slug}", name="trick_edit")
 */
public function editTrick(Trick $trick, Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader, Filesystem $filesystem): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

    $originalMediaPictures = new ArrayCollection();

    // Create an ArrayCollection of the current mediaPicture objects in the database
    foreach ($trick->getMediaPictures() as $mediaPicture) {
        $originalMediaPictures->add($mediaPicture);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(TrickFormType::class, $trick);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $slugger = new AsciiSlugger();
        $trick->setSlug($slugger->slug($trick->getTitle()));
        $trick->setUserEditor($this->getUser());
        $trick->setEditedDate(new \DateTime('now'));

        foreach ($form->get('mediaPictures') as $picture) {
            $file = $picture->get('name')->getData();
            if (!empty($file)) {
                $trickPictureFileName = $fileUploader->upload($file, $this->getParameter('app.trick_picture_directory'));
                $mediaPicture = new MediaPicture();
                $mediaPicture->setTrick($trick);
                $mediaPicture->setName($trickPictureFileName);
                $trick->addMediaPicture($mediaPicture);
            }
        }

        foreach ($originalMediaPictures as $mediaPicture) {
            if (!$trick->getMediaPictures()->contains($mediaPicture)) {
                $trick->getMediaPictures()->removeElement($trick);
                $filesystem->remove($this->getParameter('app.trick_picture_directory') . $mediaPicture->getName());
            }
        }

        foreach ($trick->getMediaPictures() as $mediaPicture) {
            if (empty($mediaPicture->getName())) {
                $trick->removeMediaPicture($mediaPicture);
            }
        }

        $entityManager->persist($trick);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Trick updated.');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('trick_detail', ['slug' => $trick->getSlug()]);
    }

    return $this->render('trick/edit_trick.html.twig', [
        'trick' => $trick,
        'trickForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Parent Form :

```
            ->add('mediaPictures', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => MediaPictureFormType::class,
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ])
```

ChildForm:

```
            ->add('name', FileType::class, [
            'label' => 'Picture',
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'form-control border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 rounded hover:shadow focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:bg-opacity-50 focus:border-gray-400 py-2 px-4'
            ],
            'multiple' => false,
            'row_attr' => ['class' => 'flex flex-col py-5 px-8'],
            'empty_data' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'data_class' => null,
        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is not right on this line:
`$trick->getMediaPictures()->removeElement($trick);`
You are trying to remove the `Trick` from its own collection of `MediaPictures` (it's not in there).
Maybe you mean to do something like this:

```
    foreach ($originalMediaPictures as $mediaPicture) {
        if (!$trick->getMediaPictures()->contains($mediaPicture)) {
            // $trick->getMediaPictures()->removeElement($trick);

            // remove association from $mediaPicture
            $mediaPicture->setTrick(null);
            $entityManager->persist($mediaPicture);

            // and/or delete $mediaPicture from database
            $entityManager->remove($mediaPicture);

            $filesystem->remove($this->getParameter('app.trick_picture_directory') . $mediaPicture->getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you'r right ! Thanks for that, it's better now. But i still have a problem of updating an already existing picture.. When i try to update a picture by uploading an other it adds an other but doesn't remove the old one.. If you have any idea of what's the problem could be..? Maybe mapping or ? Maybe just deleting the old picture but i don't know how to know wich picture should be deleted.

Comment: If you mean you want to edit a particular `MediaPicture` entity, you could try to make a form just for that entity and a separate controller action. Are you using vich/uploader-bundle?

Comment: I have a OneToMany relationship between Trick and MediaPicture so in my TrickFormType i have a CollectionForm of MediaPictureForm which have filetype. So in my view i have a for loop to create my inputs file. I want to update a picture by removing MediaPicture and local file and adding new when i upload a file in the input. I don't user VichUploader because it's a project where i should'nt use external bundles..